# iOS UIAutomation UIAElement.isVisible() throwing stale response?

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, iphone

I'm trying to use isVisible() within a loop to create a waitForElement type of a function for my iOS UIAutomation. When I try to use the following code, it fails while waiting for an element when a new screen pops up. The element is clearly there because if I do a delay(2) before tapping the element it works perfectly fine. How is everyone else accomplishing this, because I am at a loss...

Here's the waitForElement code that I am using:

```
function waitForElement(element, timeout, step) {
        if (step == null) {
                step = 0.5;
        }

        if (timeout == null) {
            timeout = 10;
        }

        var stop = timeout/step;

        for (var i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
                if (element.isVisible()) {
                        return;
                }
                target.delay(step);
        }
        element.logElement();
        throw("Not visible");
}
```

Comment: What if you check for existence before checking for visibility: if exists {if visible: return}

Answer (score 2):

If your page reloads during `waitForElement` function execution then you have to refresh `element` by finding it once again. Try to use `selector` as parameter an not the element and use `findElement` function:

```
function waitForElement(selector, timeout, step) {
        if (step == null) {
                step = 0.5;
        }

        if (timeout == null) {
            timeout = 10;
        }

        var stop = timeout/step;

        for (var i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
                if (driver.findElement(selector).isVisible()) {
                        return;
                }
                target.delay(step);
        }
        element.logElement();
        throw("Not visible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This waiting should be handled for you.  You can specify isVisible using a predicate or withValueForKey Try this ...

target.pushTimeout(timeout);
element.withValueForKey(1, "isVisible");
target.popTimeout();